# Referring in vignette to .Rd files

Tags: r

Is there possibility how can I refer to .Rd files in vignette ? .Rd files are creating layout of help() function for each function in my package. I want my vignette to have all my functions mentioned one by one just like in help(). I'm not sure how can I refer to them. My attempts was :

````
title: "introduction"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{introduction}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

```{r, include = FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  collapse = TRUE,
  comment = "#>"
)
```

```{r setup}
library(megapackage)
help(hello)
help(myfun1)
````

but vignette instead of giving help(hello) and help(myfun1) it's giving just text 'help(hello)' and 'help(myfun1)'. I tried also ??hello and ??myfun1 but result was the same. Do you have guys any idea, how can I do it ?